# TestNG DataProvider - How to produce all permutations in a List

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider

Supposed I have a list of string, I want a `DataProvider` to produce permutation of 2 of that list to use as 2 parameter in one of the test function. What I have so far is:

```
@DataProvider(name = "Permutation")
public static Object[][] permutations() {
    List <String> permutations = getPermutationList();
    Object[][] dataList = new Object[permutations.size()][permutations.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < permutations.size(); i++) {
        dataList[i] = new Object[permutations.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < permutations.size(); j++) {
            dataList[i][j] = permutations.get(i);
        }
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

My `DataProvider` doesn't work as expected, every row is just null.

Any hint please? Thank you

Comment: Where are node and nodeTypeList populated?

Comment: editted, just a function and class that i use to get the list of permutation

Comment: If you have a debugger (or do a `System.out`), I would try to see what the value of `permutations.get(i)` actually yields.

Answer (score 0):

The `getPermutationList` is the issue with your code.  Ensure it's returning the data you are expecting.  Below is the same code as above, only with a hardcoded array being initialized.  When it runs, there is data in the `dataList` object.

```
public static Object[][] permutations() {
    List <String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
    Object[][] dataList = new Object[permutations.size()][permutations.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < permutations.size(); i++) {
        dataList[i] = new Object[permutations.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < permutations.size(); j++) {
            dataList[i][j] = permutations.get(i);
        }
    }
    return dataList;
}
```